# how load local module before egg during unit test?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am writing unit test. and Found there's one problem, my unit test will load module from the egg before my local module. if I change some code, I need to run setup.py install again to make the unit test work.

I print sys.path and found the egg is before my local module.I guess it's the root cause.

I use Pycharm and is there solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to install the egg in `develop` mode, which will install it as a link.  This should allow you to make updates to the source without having to relink/install/uninstall.

http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#development-mode